# postcodeforUK plugin in nopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

How to use postcodes4U plugin in nopCommerce version 3.8?

I had downloaded the DLL for the plugin now I want to implement it with my nopCommerce version 3.8 based web application.

Comment: What do you mean by *i had downloaded the ddl for the plugin* ?

Comment: For this plugin no source code is being provided they only provide the dlls.Please let me know if you have the source code for this plugin.

Comment: First, if you looking for the source code, then this is a wrong place. Second, Yes, they are providing only Dlls. Moreover, you can develop  your own(*using API*), or request for source code to the provider.

Comment: Your question is pointed out, *How to use plugin* and  *I want to implement it* This are two different things. one is just configuration and second is for development, which is too broad.

Comment: @Div Thanks you are absolutely right. I had achieved it by registering myself to postcode4U website and get 30 credit. After that  I installed that plugin from the nop admin section and configure it by filling the required attributes like username and API key.

Comment: Yes, so all you need is configuration of plugin. And not to develop :)